# Putting a delay time in the automatic startup of certain application when the computer starts

Tags: windows-7, boot, 64-bit, skype, intel-core-i3

I now have a licensed version of Window 7 Home basic 64 bit.

Installed memory RAM →  8GB

**Usable** → 7.82GB

I won't say that the system is not fast, but not too much fast as I anticipated that I will have after migrating from a  32 bit architecture to a 64 bit architecture.

I think there is a certain software that is slowing down the speed may be avast antivirus.

Question #2 → I think lot depends upon the processor not just RAM?

Question # 3 → Is it possible that I can queue up certain application to start when the windows is restarted. The boot up time is quite high at the moment, and I want to increase the performance by decrease this time frame. Something Like this →

1. Skype should start automatically after 5 minutes.
2. Wamp should start after 12 minutes.

Currently they all start one after another or may be simultaneously and this increases the startup or boot time.

That means assigning a time lag when these applications will autostart after boot. This will help me to get the **fully working chrome at boot** in less time. while I will read my emails gradually the applications I mentioned will start.

This will ensure the fast window start up. Because generally until all the applications have been started even the chrome takes a lot of time to start for the first time. Aligning the applications mentioned above will optimize my system for better speed at window initialization or startup or boot.

Comment: I believe there's a setting in services somewhere that you can select "delayed startup". Not sure about applications though

Comment: so this setting, if exists, will delay all the applications?

Comment: try this software: http://www.r2.com.au/page/products/show/startup-delayer/

Comment: I have tried that programme. That is a paid one. Its free version doesn't allow you to schedule, bit it allows batch scheduling not app based scheduling.

Comment: I was looking for someone who can guide me this w/o an app if possible through some batch scripting.

Comment: @Champion you can enable that setting for specific services only

Comment: run task scheduler , create a new task, in trigger select run at logon and add a delay that you like. Repeat this for all tools

Comment: 64-bit versions of Windows Home Basic don't exist, how were you able to install a 64-but version of it, if no ISOs exist?

Comment: Iso exists microsoft chat support helped me to download this. Let me show you the proof → https://s3.amazonaws.com/projectsts/Think+Centre/Home+Basic+64+bit.png If you wish I can give you the iso.

Comment: Check this → https://www.screencast.com/t/tnmvzK1Es

Comment: @Ramhound you mean the Starter edition. Home Basic is available as 32 and 64Bit.

Comment: I posted the steps to run programs via Task Scheduler with a delay.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I must be thinking Starter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `Task Scheduler` from start menu

[image]

create a new task

[image]

add the trigger "at logon" and here you can select the delay:

[image]

under `Actions` click on `New` and select the program you want to start.

[image]

Click ok to create the task. Repeat this for all programs you like to start and use [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to remove the normal startup entries for the programs.